# ios: memory usage when reading a big file

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I need to import some files in my iOS app and forward the data to another layer (via MessagePack).

The imported file can be quite big, so I can't load it entirely in memory and I must read and forward it by chunks.
To do so, I'm using a `NSInputStream`, and every time it gives me a bit of data, I pack it and forward it.
But strangely, doing so doesn't change the memory usage of the process, as if the chunks of data were note released immediately.

The process could be simulated by this piece of code, where I create random data and extract its bytes (that's the main part of the MessagePack packing, that uses the memory):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    NSData *theData = [self generateRandomData];
    const char *buf = ((NSData*)theData).bytes;
}
```

The memory usage skyrockets and reach ~450MB (the `generateRandomData` creates a 2MB piece of data), and then decreases after the end of the `for` loop to its regular level.

I would have thought that the `buf` variable should be released after every loop iteration, and therefore the memory usage never go very high.

Why isn't the case? Am I missing something?

How could I import a big file like this then? I was thinking about making a short break during the process (every 100MB imported or so) to let the memory usage decrease, but it doesn't seem ideal to me.

Comment: When using ARC the memory deallocation is not in our hand and it is decided by the system. Interesting thing about this is that the same location in the stack is being overloaded as you said. Upvoted.

Comment: @arqam, you are wrong. It's in environment with garbage collection deallocation is decided by the system. In ARC like in MRC memory is managed by programmer, but in more convenient way.

Comment: Have you checked app for memory leaks?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Then when we are not manually releasing resources then how does ARC release if its not happening like garbage collection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also face the same problem of memory utilisation in my application as it reaches to 600 mb ,then i release the memory manually by using an autorelease pool .

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
            {
            NSData *theData = [self generateRandomData];

@autoreleasepool {       
     const char *buf = ((NSData*)theData).bytes;
             }    

         }
```

Create an autorelease pool and then check your memory utilisation .Hope this Helps you.

Comment: What was the result you getting from this? Because the iterations are still inside the `autoreleasepool`.

Comment: I did accept this answer because the solution was indeed to put the `buf` inside an `autoreleasepool`, but @arqam is right, the `@autoreleasepool` should be inside the for loop, so the `buf` variable is released at every iteration. @mukul maybe you could edit your answer so others aren't misled?